# RDLC report generate white space when print on first page set to false

Tags: wpf, rdlc

I am doing WPF with RDLC report. My RDLC report show white space at the bottom of the report . The size is exactly same as my header. The white space will gone if is set `printOnfirstpage = true` and join up with page 2. The space should contain page 2 item instead of showing white space .

I also set ConsumeContainerWhitespace to True , but it still not helping

May I know is that any setting or margin problem ?